# Notify users when an edit will cause a revision

Tags: feature-request, edits

For chat, a tip appears when a message is too old to edit:

[image]

It would be nice if something like this were to show:

[image]

Comment: And if you hit submit at 4:59:999?

Comment: Haha, couldn't you do that before? I'm not asking for a timer, but a notification for when the post will generate a new revision would be cool. I usually check on the post and see if it passed `5 minutes` before editing anyways.

Comment: What would be the advantage of this? How would you change your behavior?

Comment: I would fix any trivial errors within the 5 minutes allotted. After that, I would reconsider fixing one character edits on my own posts.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I was afraid of. Why would we want to discourage people from fixing problems with their posts? That's a good thing. Please don't stop.

Comment: @Cody Because there's not a very good reason to add a new revision *just* to change one character

Comment: @Doorknob Why not? Creating a revision is free, it doesn't cost anything. It's a way of tracking changes over time. Would you *not* check in a fix to your source control system because it was too minor to justify creating a revision?

Comment: @Cody Uhh... That's a good point :P The only actual downside I see is that it pushes you that much closer to Community Wiki, but still that's not really anything to worry about. It just feels... Odd :P

Comment: @CodyGray If my source control punished me for making too many revisions, I'd also think twice before checking in a minor edit.